# Low-res photos when transferred from iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, camera

I have an iPhone 4S running iOS 8.1.0

When I take photos using the built-in camera app, and transfer them off my phone using DropBox or PhotoSync the photos mostly end up as low-res versions. Not all of them, but about 90%.

I've spent some time trying to work out what is going on and its melting my brain.

Things I know:

1. The problem is related somehow to the iPhone camera app as it doesn't happen with Camera+.
2. The photos do exist on my phone at full-res. If I plug my phone into the laptop with the USB cable, a drive gets mounted and I can get to my photos, copy them off and they are there basking in their high-res glory. That rules out any dumb stuff like 'was I using the front-facing camera' or 'have you set the phone to store photos at low-res'.
3. If I use DropBox or PhotoSync they come through as (mostly) low-res.
4. I'm not doing anything with iCloud as I know that causes lower-res versions.

Any help would be appreciated as it is doing my head in!

Comment: Are you offered full-res versions when you email the photos to yourself?

Comment: @user24601, no it just attaches the image without asking anything

Comment: But when you click Send, does it prompt you to pick a size?

Comment: @user24601 Yes, when I click send it does ask me what size to use

Comment: What happens when you click the largest size available?

Comment: @user24601 It sends it as the largest size available. I have not had issues sending emails with low-res photos. It has just been when I use DropBox or PhotoSync.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem was fixed in either iOS 8.1.2 or possibly 8.1.1.

Running iOS 8.1.2, I have tested the same photos from my Camera Roll that gave me the issues described and they now transfer at the correct resolution.